# XSL/XML add nodes to create a total

Tags: xml, function, xslt

I'm a a novice at XML/XSL and believe I need a function for this request.

I have a form that needs to have a total for nodes w/the same name.

-----------------TOTAL Section--------------------------

```
<th align="left"><font size="2"><xsl:text>Total Freight & Other Charges:
</xsl:text></font></th>
<td><font size="2"> $<xsl:value-of select='format-number(Document-810/SUMMARY/SAC/SAC05, "###,###,##0.00")'/></font></td>
```

-------------section for individual nodes---------

```
<xsl:for-each select="Document-810/SUMMARY/SAC">
<tr>
<th align="left"><xsl:text>Amount</xsl:text></th>
<td colspan="2"><font size="2"><xsl:value-of select="concat('$', format-number(SAC05 div 100, '###,###,###.00'))" />
</font>   
</td>
<th align="left"><font size="2"><xsl:text>Description</xsl:text></font></th>
<td colspan="7"><font size="2">
<xsl:value-of select="SAC15"/></font>
</td>           
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Predefined functions are summarized in http://maxtoroq.github.io/xpath-ref/ or https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/, for instance. So check there first whether you find something doing the job. If you need further help then consider to add a small but representative sample of the XML and show us exactly which values you want to use to compute which total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the input XML that is being used for transformation is as below

```
<Document-810>
    <SUMMARY>
        <SAC>
            <SAC05>1000</SAC05>
            <SAC15>Description 1</SAC15>
        </SAC>
        <SAC>
            <SAC05>2000</SAC05>
            <SAC15>Description 2</SAC15>
        </SAC>
        <SAC>
            <SAC05>3000</SAC05>
            <SAC15>Description 3</SAC15>
        </SAC>
        <SAC>
            <SAC05>4000</SAC05>
            <SAC15>Description 4</SAC15>
        </SAC>
        <SAC>
            <SAC05>5000</SAC05>
            <SAC15>Description 5</SAC15>
        </SAC>
    </SUMMARY>
</Document-810>
```

you can use the following code snippet to calculate the sum of the values in all `<SAC05>` nodes in the context of `<SUMMARY>` node.

```
<xsl:variable name="totalAmt" select="sum(SAC/SAC05) div 100" />
```

and then use the `concat()` and `format-number()` functions to display the value in `$XXX.XX` format.

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat('$', format-number($totalAmt, '###,###,##0.00'))"/>
```

Below is the XSLT that can be used to get the HTML table (*you can use it as a reference and change the table structure as per your requirement*).

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output method="html" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="SUMMARY">
        <html>
            <body>
                <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th align="left"><font size="2"><xsl:text>Total Freight &amp; Other Charges:</xsl:text></font></th>
                        <td align="left"><font size="2">
                                <xsl:variable name="totalAmt" select="sum(SAC/SAC05) div 100" />
                                <xsl:value-of select="concat('$', format-number($totalAmt, '###,###,##0.00'))"/>
                            </font></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th align="left"><font size="2"><xsl:text>Amount</xsl:text></font></th>
                        <th align="left"><font size="2"><xsl:text>Description</xsl:text></font></th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="SAC">
                        <tr>
                            <td><font size="2"><xsl:value-of select="concat('$', format-number(SAC05 div 100, '###,###,###.00'))" /></font></td>
                            <td><font size="2"><xsl:value-of select="SAC15" /></font></td> 
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

[image: HTML Output]

Comment: This is pefect!  Thank you so much again for your assistance.